# c# - how to do subtraction between two columns in different listview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 2 listviews with specific column, but I can't do subtraction with it. In listview 1 I have 7 columns, and 5 columns in listview 2. I want to subtract column "banyak" in listview 2 with "banyak" in listview 1. when I put this code, the data doesn't come in listview. but i can compile the program. please help me! here is my codes:

In listview 1

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select nama_peminjam,nobp_nip,nohp,nama_komponen,jenis_komponen,peminjaman_alat.banyak,tanggal from db_coba.peminjaman_alat,db_coba.list_komponen where db_coba.peminjaman_alat.komponen_id=db_coba.list_komponen.komponen_id";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            baca = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            peminjaman_alat.Items.Clear();

            while (baca.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(baca["nama_peminjam"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["nobp_nip"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["nohp"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["nama_komponen"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["jenis_komponen"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["banyak"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["tanggal"].ToString());

                peminjaman_alat.Items.Add(item);


            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

in listview 2

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select nama_komponen,list_komponen.status,jenis_komponen,nfc_tag,list_komponen.banyak,peminjaman_alat.banyak from db_coba.list_komponen,db_coba.peminjaman_alat where db_coba.list_komponen.komponen_id=db_coba.peminjaman_alat.komponen_id";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            baca = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            listkomponen.Items.Clear();



            while (baca.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(baca["nama_komponen"].ToString());

                item.SubItems.Add(baca["jenis_komponen"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["nfc_tag"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["banyak"].ToString());                
                item.SubItems.Add(baca["status"].ToString());
                if (peminjaman_alat.SelectedIndices.Count == 0) return;

                string banyak_peminjaman = peminjaman_alat.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
                item.SubItems[3].Text = (Int32.Parse(item.SubItems[3].Text) - Int32.Parse(banyak_peminjaman)).ToString();

                listkomponen.Items.Add(item);

            }


            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

I hope you can understand what I meant.

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint where the operation takes place and run through debugger?

Comment: This form of treating UI controls as business objects makes my nails curl. It seems that 80% of all WinForms questions are like that.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is redundant in the context

Comment: Data doesn't come in the listview or does not come in db command.?

Comment: data doesn't come in listview

Comment: Cool, exception handlers catching everything and just close the connection, that is very helpful during problem analysis. You could start by removing those harmful try/catch blocks, and handle connections through `using` blocks that handle disposing of your connection as well. And either choose to handle exceptions (not ignoring them like here) or to let them fly so that you actually know what happens

Comment: okay, i'll try it first

Answer (score 0):

Just Check this Function. Reference Link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx) 
Sample Image Ref [image]

```
    public void AddItemsOne()
    {
        // Set the view to show details.
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1",0);
        // Place a check mark next to the item.
        //item1.Checked = true;
        item1.SubItems.Add("1");
        item1.SubItems.Add("2");
        item1.SubItems.Add("3");           
        item1.SubItems.Add("4");

        // Create columns for the items and subitems.
        // Width of -2 indicates auto-size.
        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Sub Column One", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Sub Column Two", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Sub Column Three", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Sub Column Four", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        //Add the items to the ListView.
        listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1 });

        // Add the ListView to the control collection.
        this.Controls.Add(listView1);                   
    }
```